# Django - admin changeForm extra content beside a field

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-admin

In the admin change_form of one of my objects I need to have extra content in a certain field (like buttons which will do some javascript modifications on this field)

I took a look at the original `change_form` template and I see that I can add things to the block `content` but how can I add that just beside a certain field ?

Example:

```
<!-- ... -->
<div class="form-row part">
  <div>
    <label for="id_part" class="required">Part:</label>
    <input id="id_part" type="text" class="vIntegerField" value="1" name="part" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row text">
  <div>
    <label for="id_text" class="required">Text:</label>
    <textarea id="id_text" rows="10" cols="40" name="text" class="vLargeTextField"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row sequence">
  <div>
    <label for="id_sequence" class="required">Sequence:</label>
    <input id="id_sequence" type="text" class="vIntegerField" value="3" name="sequence" />
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Would become

```
<!-- ... -->
<div class="form-row part">
  <div>
    <label for="id_part" class="required">Part:</label>
    <input id="id_part" type="text" class="vIntegerField" value="1" name="part" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row text">
  <div>
    <label for="id_text" class="required">Text:</label>
    <textarea id="id_text" rows="10" cols="40" name="text" class="vLargeTextField"></textarea>
  </div>
<!-- extra content start -->
  <div class="markup-tools">
    <input type="button" class="tool1" value="Tool 1" />
    <input type="button" class="tool2" value="Tool 2" />
    <input type="button" class="tool3" value="Tool 3" />
  </div>
<!-- extra content end -->
</div>
<div class="form-row sequence">
  <div>
    <label for="id_sequence" class="required">Sequence:</label>
    <input id="id_sequence" type="text" class="vIntegerField" value="3" name="sequence" />
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Is there a way to do that without having to append the content with JS like:

```
$('.form-row.text').append('the content');
```

I find that not very maintainable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is, but the js way is much easier.

You need to create a custom widget class, then set the particular field to use that widget. Example:

```
class FooWidget(Widget):
    def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
        output = super(FooWidget, self).render(*args, **kwargs)
        output += "<p>I'm a widget!</p>"
        return mark_safe(output)

class BarAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = { models.TextField: {'widget': FooWidget} }
```

This will override all TextField fields with your custom FooWidget.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently not.

I had to do several

```
$('.form-row.text').append('the content');
```

To put extra content